# SwiftUI - Difference between Spacer() and Color.clear?

Tags: layout, transparent, swiftui

Pretty simple question - I'm just curious if there is any perceivable difference between `Spacer()` and `Color.clear` in SwiftUI

Comment: `Spacer()` is used in `VStack` and `HStack` for *placement* of Views. `Color.clear` is just that - a *color*. If you want, add a background color to two `Texts` in a `VStack`. They'll appear right above each other in the center of any screen. Now, add a *single* `Spacer()` between the two texts. They are now at the top and bottom. Now, replace all that with a single `Rectangle()`. Try to add a "spacer" modifier - there is no such thing. But try adding a `background` modifier with a `Color.clear`. It works. To me, you're trying to compare apples and oranges.

Answer (score 0):

If you measure the screen, then yes.
I notice a ~2px difference when using both as in this example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            Text("First")
            Spacer()
            Text("Second")
            Spacer() 
        }
    }
}
```

Which generates:

[image: spacer]

(the middle space takes around 84px)

Now using `Color.clear`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Color.clear
            Text("First")
            Color.clear
            Text("Second")
            Color.clear
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image: Color.clear]

Notice that the "**First**" and "**Second**" strings don't touch the vertical guide anymore...

(the middle "space" now takes around 86px)

Not a huge difference, but I would stick to `Spacer`.

([xScope](https://xscopeapp.com) is our friend)